# Inferring generic arguments when casting

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-conversion

Assume I have a generic class `Generic<T>`. Initializing it can be done in the following way

```
Generic<String> gen = new Generic<String>();
```

Sine Java 7, the generic argument can be inferred

```
Generic<String> gen = new Generic<>();
```

I was wondering why this isn't being done for casting (`gen2` is a subclass of `Generic<String>`):

```
Generic<String> gen = (Generic<String>) gen2; // Compiles
Generic<String> gen = (Generic<>) gen2;       // Doesn't compile
```

I tried to think of a pitfall or some ambiguity, but couldn't find any. Is there a reason for this being a bad idea? Was it proposed and not implemented for some reason?

Comment: If it's already the right type, you don't need to cast, right?

Comment: However, consider that in the non-initialization case, you can't infer the type, in general (the RHS will typically be non-trivial, e.g. `((Generic<>)gen2).doStuff(74)`).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This is just a simplified example. I edited with `gen2` being a subclass to make the cast meaningful. In the example you gave what does `doStuff(74)` return? If it can't be cast due to being the wrong type then this is a different issue.

Comment: I think the issue they were bringing up is if `doStuff` is a method that depends on the generic type of `gen2` (or rather the expression it is invoked on), what should be inferred for that invocation?

Comment: Yes, what @SotiriosDelimanolis said.  You've shown a degenerate case where the type *could* be inferred.  In any non-degenerate case, there'd be no way to infer the type.